# Wordpress clauses don't load when using Ajax

Tags: php, wordpress

I was wondering if there was a method I needed to use in order to use the wordpress clauses more than once on the same page.

When the page loads, the clauses are included in the WP_Query called by a function.

I try to refresh this data through ajax. I call the same function, the query loads. But all of the sql defined by the clauses are left out.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use multiple custom WP_Query loops on the same page you will need to use wp_reset_postdata() between them.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Multiple_Loops

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata